# This pattern in any language

Tags: algorithm, console-application, geometry

I am trying to understand this pattern, how the rows and columns equation could be so that I could make a loop to give me the same picture.
I don't necessarily need the code, just the way the pattern go, I can't seem to understand it have tried coding it still my results are bad...

When my input is 1 this is the result
[image: When my input is 1]

When my input is 3 this is the result
[image]

And when my input is 15 this is the result
[image]

Comment: you should add what you have tried and maybe stick to one language

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - actually, he wants to discuss the alghoritm, not the code itself.

Comment: @libik, that does not mean the OP cannot provide at least some attempt

Comment: @libik actually, he wants someone to write the algorithm for himself, because I don't see any attempt to do something.

Comment: "Bresenham's algorithm" it is called. Also known as the "dual differential engine" GIYF

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a rough pixelated circle. So the equation is *x^2 + y^2 <= r^2*. Where the coordinate values are taken relative to the center, the radius given as input.

*Edit:* Upon further inspection, these are very *wide* circles, presumably to account for the rectangular shape of the character cels. So, it should be more like *(x/scale)^2 + y^2 <= r^2*

As mentioned in the comments, the keyword to learn more is "Bresenham's circle-drawing algorithm", which is a fast way to do the calculations for one quadrant of the circle (and the rest you get by mirroring). Using Bresenham, you'll probably also need a flood fill. You might also search for "scan-line rasterization of circle", which can skip the flood-fill step.

Comment: Bresenham is a cool algorithm, but the wrong choice for this problem.  @Alper Cinar actually has a much better answer.  You need to draw the ASCII-art background anyway.  His method adds only constant effort per character.

Comment: @Gene Agreed + upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

This is an ASCII-art circle with radius (r) equal to the input number.

Double X and double dot (XX and ..) are used as pixel contents.

We can just impose a coordinate system [-r..r, -r..r] on the pixel matrix and test each one for membership inside the circle of given radius as we print it. The test is x^2 + y^2 <= r^2.

The following C function does all this. It produces correct output for all of your inputs (1,3,15).

```
void print_filled_circle(int r)
{
    for (int x = -r; x <= r; x++)
    {
        for (int y = -r; y <= r; y++)
        {
            if (x*x + y*y <= r*r)
                printf("XX");
            else
                printf("..");            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why your answer was down-voted. It's simple and correct.

Comment: @Gene maybe because it encourages people to treat SO as a code writing service

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Maybe, but more likely the Bresenham advocate.

Comment: @AlperCinar Thanks, i understand the logic behind now! I even played around a bit making a circle within the circle.. And even playing with other Shapes with that method...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How would you suggest we learn programming? Because I come here asking questions whenever i try a couple of times n fail, I always learn something new here..